# geom_histogram in ggplot rounds data up when placing in bins, how do I change this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am putting together a histogram to look at how my data is bunched around a threshold [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYLn0.jpg). I was surprised to see that the spike appeared to be to the right of the threshold (the red vertical line) rather than to the left. Using the geom_build function, I saw that observations were being rounded up. In this graph, for example, the spike should be at 1305, but with a bin width of 1, it appears at 1305.5, where the bin takes in values between 1304.5 and 1305.5. I.e. it is rounding upwards.

(I know this is the case, because as I reduce the bin size, the spike approaches 1305, which is where I know it really is.)

I can't find any setting in ggplot to change this, and I'm not quite sure if it's even possible. An alternative would be to change the bins to match integers, ie to go from 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 .. rather than .5-1.5,1.5-2.5 etc.

My code is below. I'd be grateful for any advice.

```
plotcars<-ggplot(data=cars_total) +
geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, aes(x=V3,weight=V1)) +
geom_vline(data=cuts, aes(xintercept=vals, linetype=Thresholds,
colour = Thresholds), show.legend = TRUE) + 
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1300,1350),ylim=c(0,800000)) +
scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)

plotcars
```

Comment: Try setting up a `center` or `boundary` parameter. Quoting `geom_histogram` help: _For example, to center on integers, use width = 1 and boundary = 0.5_.

Comment: Please could you give us a source for the data so that we can recreate your example? It's easier to answer the question if we can visualise it and check the variables ourselves.

Comment: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/co2-cars-emission-8 

This is the data source - at least the bulk of it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, @ajrwhite the relevant columns of the data are selected in the below code:
cars_1314<-rbind(,cars2013[,14:16],deparse.level = 1)
cars2014_ext<-rbind(cars2014[,7:16],cars2013[,7:16],deparse.level = 1)
cars_total<rbind(cbind(cars2014[,14],cars2014[,16]),cbind(cars2011[,14],cars2011[,16]),cbind(cars2012[,14],cars2012[,16]),cbind(cars2013[,14],cars2013[,16]),deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE)
cars_total<-as.data.frame(cars_total)

# Adding an extra column to cars_total, with the reference mass of the car. 
cars_total$V3<-cars_total$V2+25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I was using the `geom_histogram`, when I should have been using `geom_stat`.

Quoting from `?geom_bar`:

> `stat_count` counts the number of cases at each x position. If you want to bin the data in ranges, you should use `stat_bin` instead.

The replacement code is:

```
+ stat_count(geom="bar", aes(weight=Registrations,width = 1, center=0))
```